# Insert R object into json string

Tags: r

I am sending an email from a Shiny app via the SendGrid API using the HTTR package (using POST function with json encoding). I need to pass an R object in between the json quotes that are used to define the text body of the email:

I have tried to convert the R object to json as follows:

```
client_id<- "f432jj"

email_text<- paste("Below is your unique  key:", client_id, "Please copy 
your key to the clipboard, then click 'Begin'")

email_text<- jsonlite::toJSON(email_text)
```

Here is the json code into which I need to insert the email_text object.

`body = '{"from": {"email":"xxx@gmail.com"},
     "personalizations": [{"to": [{"email":"zzz@gmail.com"}],
        "dynamic_template_data":{
          "header":"A measure is ready to be completed",
          "text": email_text,
          "c2a_button":"Begin",
          "c2a_link":"yyy@gmail.com"}}],
      "template_id":"e-98766334"}'`

When trying to pass in the email_text object as above and send the email, I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

I think this means the syntax is wrong.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you wouldn't build your body JSON data as a string. You could build the list that represents the data and then let jsonlite turn it into a JSON string for you. Your example might look something like this

```
client_id<- "f432jj"
email_text<- paste("Below is your unique  key:", client_id, "Please copy 
your key to the clipboard, then click 'Begin'")

body <- list(
     from = list(email="xxx@gmail.com"),
     personalizations = list(list(to=list(list(email="zzz@gmail.com")))),
     dynamic_template_data = list(
       header="A measure is ready to be completed",
       text = email_text,
       c2a_button = "Begin",
       c2a_link = "yyy@gmail.com"
     ),
     template_id = "e-98766334"
     )

jsonlite::toJSON(body,auto_unbox=TRUE)
```

Comment: This is a really good answer and has pointed us in the right direction. The email is now sending with a 202 message, which is good. However the problem is that the body text of the email and the button details (label and link) are not being rendered. I've tried using data.frame() instead of list to define the components of `dynamic_template_data` but this hasn't worked.

Comment: In fact, I don't think any of the components of dynamic_template_data are rendering. When we were passing in the raw json we could get text to appear in the email body.